# How do I reset Sharepoint homepage to its initial default?

Tags: 2010, site

I accidentally set one of the pages I was working on as my current Site's homepage (thinking it would just become the default page for a directory, HTML-style). Is it possible to undo that change, and reset my Sharepoint homepage to the one that it came shipped with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint designer, I was able to revert to the original homepage by doing the following:

1. Navigate to All Files
2. Open the Pages folder
3. Right-click on `default.aspx`
4. Click "Set as Home Page" in the context menu.

[image: example]